# How to pass 2 values to a view in MVC using "model: data" logic?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, controller, parameter-passing

I have a `JavaScript` that sends a `querystring` to a `Controller`:

```
window.location.href = "/Error/Index?message=" + data.responseJSON.Message;
```

And I have a method in the controller that takes `message` as a parameter and displays the message in the view:

```
public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    return View("Error", model: message);
}
```

The View Logic:

```
<strong>Application Error:</strong><br /> @Model
```

How can I modify the logic, so I can send 2 parameters in the querystring and display them in the View?

Something like that:

JavaScript:

```
 window.location.href = "/Error/Index?message=" + data.responseJSON.Message + "&stackTrace" + data.responseJSON.StackTrace;
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string errorMessage, string stackTrace)
{
    return View("Error", model: errorMessage);
}
```

View:

```
<strong>Application Error:</strong><br /> @Model.errorMessage <br>
<span>@Model.stackTrace</span>
```

Is there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}
```

Set your view to use that view model:

```
@model MyViewModel

<strong>Application Error:</strong><br /> @Model.ErrorMessage <br>
<span>@Model.StackTrace</span>
```

Then send an instance of that view model to your view:

```
return View("Error", model: new MyViewModel { ErrorMessage = errorMessage, StackTrace = stackTrace });
```

If you don't want to create a separate class for this, something like a `Tuple<string, string>` would work just as well as a view model, just with less intuitive property names.  Any type can be a view model.  You just need to specify that type in the `@model` declaration at the top of the view and pass an instance of that type to the view.

**Edit:** If you want to use a `Tuple<string, string>` then the setup would be the same as any type.  Declare and use the type in the model:

```
@model Tuple<string, string>

<strong>Application Error:</strong><br /> @Model.Item1 <br>
<span>@Model.Item2</span>
```

And pass an instance of that type to the model:

```
return view("Error", model: new Tuple<string, string>(errorMessage, stackTrace));
```

Be aware of the unintuitive naming though.  "Item1" and "Item2" don't really convey any information about what those values are.

---

Side note for OP and future readers... Using a `string` as a view model is probably not a good idea.  Overloads to the `View()` method can get confusing when passing a string intended to be a model but interpreted as, say, a view name.  In general it's best to use custom (or at least non-primitive) types as view models.  Even if those types have or need only one property.

Comment: Interesting idea with `Tuple`. Can you show me how can I use that in my code? Sorry, for asking, I'm not sure 100% how to implement your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: @gene: I've updated the answer with an example.  It's the same as any other class, really.  You just declare/use it in the view, and pass an instance of it from the controller to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply using an ajax call?

Something such as:

```
function aFunction()
{
    var json = '{Message: ' + //MessageParam + ', StackTrace: ' + //StackParam + '}';
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("//function", "//Controller")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'Application/json',
        success: function (result)
        {
            //Whatever you want to happen next
        }
    });

}
```